# Can Joins between views and table hurt performance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am new in sql server,

my manager has given me job where i have to find out performance of query in sql server 2008.

That query is very complex having joins between views and table. I read in internet that joins between views and table cause performance hurt?

If any expert can help me on this? Any good link where i found knowledge of this? How to calculate query performance in sql server?

Answer (score 4):

Look at the query plan - it *could* be anything. Missing indexes on one of the underlying view tables, missing indexes on the join table or something else.

Take a look at this article by Gail Shaw about finding performance issues in SQL Server - [part 1](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/finding-the-causes-of-poor-performance-in-sql-server,-part-1/), [part 2](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/finding-the-causes-of-poor-performance-in-sql-server,-part-2/).

Comment: Thanks Oded, I will definetly go through these link.

Answer (score 3):

A view (that isn't indexed/materialised) is just a macro: no more, no less

That is, it [expands into the outer query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user:27535%20%2bview%20%2bmacro). So a join with 3 views (with 4, 5, and 6 joins respectively) becomes a single query with 15 JOINs.

This is a common "I can reuse it" mistake: DRY doesn't usually apply to SQL code.

Otherwise, see Oded's answer

Answer (score 1):

Oded is correct, you should definitely start with the query plan.  That said, there are a couple of things that you can already see at a high level, for example:

> CONVERT(VARCHAR(8000), CN.Note) LIKE '%T B9997%'

`LIKE` searches with a wildcard at the front are bad news in terms of performance, because of the way indexes work.  If you think about it, it's easy to find all people in the phone book whose name starts with "Smi".  If you try to find all people who have "mit" anywhere in their name, you will find that you need to read the entire phone book.  SQL Server does the same thing - this is called a full table scan, and is typically quite slow.  The other issue is that the left side of the condition uses a function to modify the column (specifically, converting it to a varchar).  Essentially, this again means that SQL Server cannot use an index, even if there was one for the column CN.Note.

My guess is that the column is a `text` column, and that you will not be allowed to change the filter logic to remove the wildcard at the beginning of the search.  In this case, I would recommend looking into [Full-Text Search / Indexing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142559.aspx) functionality.  By enabling full text indexing, and using specific keywords such as `CONTAINS`, you should get better performance.

Again (as with all performance optimisation scenarios), you should still start with the query plan to see if this really is the biggest problem with the query.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel I just checked views, Indexes are not there. Will it create performence issue?

Comment: @HemantKothiyal - in this case, I don't believe your query would make use of the index, even if it was there (for reasons I mentioned above).  In general though, yes, correct indexing allows you to resolve most query performance issues.  The topic is too broad to even begin to cover in a comment, I would recommend you read up on indexes and optimisation.  A relatively good place to start is [here](http://use-the-index-luke.com/), although something like [this](http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Microsoft%C2%AE-SQL-Server%C2%AE-2008/dp/0735626030) goes into more detail.